# How do I use my supervised ML model with unsupervised data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I made a decision trees and logistical regression model. I am satisfied with the results. How do I use it on unsupervised data?
Also: Will I need to always use StandardScaler to new data?

Answer (score 1):

While your question is too broad for SO I still want to give some short advices:

1. You need supervised data just for training stage of your model. When you already have trained model you can make predictions on unsupervised data (i.e. data that have no labels/targets) and model returns predicted labels. Usually you can do it by using `predict` method
2. Important moment: to use the `predict` method, it is necessary to transfer data to the model input in the same form as it was during training - the same set of features and the same number of features (excluding labels/targets of course)
3. The same goes for preprocessing - if you used `StandardScaler` for training data you must use it for new data too - the SAME StandardScaler (i.e. call `transform` method of already fitted on trining data scaler)
4. The philosophy of using `StandatdScaler` or some normalisation: is short - use it for linear model (and for your logistic regression). Read about it here for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_scaling_importance.html
   But for trees it is not necessary. Example: https://towardsdatascience.com/do-decision-trees-need-feature-scaling-97809eaa60c6